# Is there anyway I can raise an event when a value in a local setting changes in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have a LongListSelector in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app (C#) which has the following XAML code:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-22,0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Packages}"
                    SelectionChanged="ItemSelected"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listItemTemplate}"/>
```

The LongListSelector is populated with values parsed from a JSON string stored in a Local Setting (`ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings`). The local setting can be changed by external factors.

My question is: Is there any way I can monitor the setting key for changes and raise an event to update the UI with the new values?

Comment: What do you mean by *external factors*?

Comment: @Romasz I mean that they will be updated by background tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to monitor the settings key for changes but you should be able to create some sort of utility class (with event handler) that you use to add items into the local settings.

Adding/Removing an item using the utility class should trigger a change-event which you can subscribe/unsubscribe to in your code.

Here's a good tutorial on how to add a [custom event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) in your class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a ton for your suggestion! I got it working. (Can't upvote, sorry :( New to StackOverflow...)